# ios uibutton hidden: does this automatically make the button disabled?

Tags: ios, uibutton, hidden

I just have a knowledge question about UIButtons / iOS in general.

Let's say you have a UIButton. You set the 'hidden' property to YES. This makes it no longer visible in view, right? But I noticed that while it's no longer visible, it is also no longer clickable either. So, does this mean that setting hidden = YES also sets enabled = NO?

Just curious. Thanks y'all.

Comment: since it is not visible, how do you know it is not clickable?

Comment: It surely would have been quicker to test this rather than write a question and wait for a response ;)

Comment: it was more for curiosity's sake - so I guess I wasn't quite that curious

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`UIButton` and all controls inherits common properties from `UIView` like `hidden`, `backgroundColor`, etc.

Class reference of `UIView` says if any view is hidden then it will not receive input events

**Class reference of `UIView` says:**

> A hidden view disappears from its window and does not receive input
>   events. It remains in its superview’s list of subviews, however, and
>   participates in autoresizing as usual. Hiding a view with subviews has
>   the effect of hiding those subviews and any view descendants they
>   might have. This effect is implicit and does not alter the hidden
>   state of the receiver’s descendants.

you can find this over [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html).

Comment: Thanks man. So - I guess this begs the question: what exactly is the difference between "enabled" and 
"userInteractionIsEnabled"?

Comment: `enabled` is not the property of `UIView`. It is a private property of `UIButton`. While `userInteractionEnabled` is the property of `UIView` which is inherited by `UIButton`. If `userInteractionEnabled` is set to `NO` then it will disable `UITouch` event of that view or button, while `enabled` will disable inputs only not `UITouch`.

Comment: Hope it will answer your next questions.

Comment: Totally yeah I appreciate your thorough and in depth response, it was exactly what I was hoping for!

Comment: Does this mean that a view behind a hidden view will receive touches or will they just be lost?

Comment: Yes, Any view just behind a hidden view will definitely receive touch events

Answer (score 2):

It does. Setting the buttons hidden property to YES will disable any user interaction. This is true for other UI elements as well as just UIButton.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can't touch button when it is hidden.If you wanna touch it then you must make it `btn.hidden = NO;`. Hidden means disable the user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure. Best way to find out would be an NSLog returning button.hidden